# How to check and change value of properties in object with typescript using loop?

Tags: typescript

I've checked some answers related to iterating or looping through, which I've managed to do it, but the problem is, I can't change value of property.

Here's the code :

```
export interface BaseOnTotalPaidFields {
    groupName: string,
    minimumTotalPaid: string,
    havePointBonus: boolean,
    pointBonus: string,
    rewardType: string,
    rewardBonus: string,
    haveReward: boolean,
    rewardPeriod: string,
}
const editMode: ComputedRef<ClubDialogEditMode> = computed(() => store.state.serviceModule.clubDialogs.vipConfigurationDialog.editMode)

let data = editMode.value.form.groupFields as BaseOnTotalPaidFields
// Or
let data : BaseOnTotalPaidFields = editMode.value.form.groupFields as BaseOnTotalPaidFields

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value])=> {
    console.log(key)
    console.log(value)
    if (value == null) {
        // Below line giving error
        data[key]  =  ''
    }
})
```

Base on above code, I'm getting below error :

`TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'BaseOnTotalPaidFields'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'BaseOnTotalPaidFields'.`

I've also tried below code and again, didn't worked :

```
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data)) {
    // Same Error.
    data[key]  =  ''
  }
```

Tried a few more solutions base on search and didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the definition of your interface as  follow :
`export interface BaseOnTotalPaidFields extends Record<string,any> {`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=68#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgIUwGdgB5JAFQhkwBsAFTBAEwDEFhbmi5RUlucAErBs0ZgB4iMKMgDmAGkxIAngD44AbwBQcPXDlQIAVzAA5TAFtgALjjTZSRbv2XkCS8ctUaDJszsHeQUXPQALTAA3YHoIZBh8CCRjIjsAIwgIWmBlEP04SHjE5NT7GWDQuChgAHdMKGYKFTBbMsdnfOq6huKUwPKnPP0I6JFugLgMrJykIb0u%20uZ6NAQICaDB7QBfbWz4ZkwaODtCEnIfOkYWdk5BAF5NAyNTC2sbAHJMd4U3JA8vC5%20FgfACMACZ3nAFCMYnEUL1UjJjMAFAU4Qkkn1Pt8Fg0mi0PsRmDjaosEYSiAdKd8YWNFjYkSiqqSGstZGtQe8dgB6blwUhQbTaUhpABWohgADpgChZMAiAAKA40ACUkvQ0AAojgwgqFQBtADWwBUqMidGRAF0VXcNDp8mIkERppLaBA5ArjSoVZVHc7sq73QrzbRkT78gh0HBgxa8Hc7nBkrRaCqtJV8ryCJwIDU4LRkHg5AhIvJeFAjIL8vllZgjSbLXoE3B3u9KjstiqgA)

Comment: Objects are index by string | number | symbol. This tells the compiler you'll never use any of those types to index it